# I am trying to make a program that splits a string of hours, into sub catagories called quadrants...Why isn't it working?

Tags: javascript

As you can see I created the array of hours in a day and want it to split into 4 quadrants of that day. I'm pretty new to programming and would love all the help I could get, thanks.

```
    let timeOfDay = (hour) => {
  hour = [`0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`,`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`,`13`,`14`,`15`,`16`,`17`,`18`,`19`,`20`,`21`,`22`,`23`,`24`];
}

let startTime = timeOfDay[17];
let endTime = '';


const Q1 = '';
const Q2 = '';
const Q3 = '';
const Q4 = '';


let quadrantIdStartTime = () => {
  if (startTime = timeOfDay(`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`)) {
    quadrantIdStartTime === Q1;
    console.log('Q1');
  } else if (startTime = timeOfDay(`7`,`8`,`9`,`10`,`11`,`12`)){
    quadrantIdStartTime === Q2;
    console.log('Q2');
  } else if (startTime = timeOfDay(`13`,`14`,`15`,`16`,`17`,`18`)){
    quadtrantIdStartTime === Q3;
    console.log('Q3');
  } else if (startTime = timeOfDay(`19`,`20`,`21`,`22`,`23`)){
    quadtrantIdStartTime === Q4;
    console.log('Q4');
  } else if ('') {
  console.log('Please enter a valid hour of day.');
  }
}

quadrantIdStartTime();
```

Comment: I'm inside codecademy making it thats why i used console.log instead of using return

Comment: `timeOfDay` does not return a value.  It is effectively not doing anything, as it is only changing the parameter passed in, which is not a persistent change once the function ends.

Comment: `let startTime = timeOfDay[17];` <= `timeOfDay` is a function so this syntax is not correct.

Comment: `if (startTime = timeOfDay(\`1\`,\`2\`,\`3\`,\`4\`,\`5\`,\`6\`)) {` <= `=` is assignment. `==` and `===` are the equality operators

Comment: Also related to that, do not use template literals (\`\`) for static strings.  There is no benefit to doing so.

Comment: You can simplify this by using indexOf an array:

`[1,2,3,4,5,6].indexOf(startTime) > -1`

Comment: `quadrantIdStartTime === Q1;` <= is using equality when it doesn't result in any difference in result.  As you can see from the comments, there are a lot of issues with this code.

Comment: wait so how do I set timeOfDay to be those 24 numbers

Comment: sorry i'm still very confused